# go json unmarshal options

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

Trying to find a simple solution to marshaling/unmashaling into the following struct

```
type Resource struct {
    Data []ResourceData `json:"data"`
}
type ResourceData struct {
    Id string  `json:"id"`
    Type string  `json:"type"`
    Attributes map[string]interface{} `json:"attributes"`
    Relationships map[string]Resource `json:"relationships"`
}
r := Resource{}
json.Unmarshal(body, &r)
```

this is great if:

```
body = `{"data":[{"id":"1","type":"blah"}]}`
```

However I also need it to respond to:

```
body = `{"data":{"id":"1","type":"blah"}}` //notice no slice
```

I could make a separate type

```
type ResourceSingle struct {
    Data ResourceData `json:"data"`
}
```

However, that would mean needing to duplicate all the functions I have attached to resource, which is possible. However, i would need to find out which type to unmarshal into before executing it, plus when it comes to the relationships part, each of those could contain data:[]{} or data{}, so that idea isn't going to work.

Alternatively I could use

```
map[string]*json.RawMessage
//or
type Resource struct {
    Data *json.RawMessage `json:"data"`
}
```

but still, when in json form how do I know if it is a slice or a node to supply the correct struct to unmarshal into?

My last resort is to umarshal into map[string]interface and use lots of reflect testing .. but this is very long winded.

Ideas?

Kind regards, jJ

Comment: In this situation, it seems more natural to change what the client is sending. Do you not have any control over that?

Comment: its the jsonapi.org spec, but thanks for answering though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a number of ways to structure it, but the simplest technique comes down to implementing a `json.Unmarshaler`, and inspecting the type of the data. You can minimally parse the json bytes, often just the first character, or you can try to unmarshal into each type and return the one that succeeds.

We'll use the latter technique here, and insert the ResourceData into a slice regardless of the incoming data's format, so we can always operate on it in the same manner:

```
type Resource struct {
    Data []ResourceData
}

func (r *Resource) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    // this gives us a temporary location to unmarshal into
    m := struct {
        DataSlice struct {
            Data []ResourceData `json:"data"`
        }
        DataStruct struct {
            Data ResourceData `json:"data"`
        }
    }{}

    // try to unmarshal the data with a slice
    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &m.DataSlice)
    if err == nil {
        log.Println("got slice")
        r.Data = m.DataSlice.Data
        return nil
    } else if err, ok := err.(*json.UnmarshalTypeError); !ok {
        // something besides a type error occurred
        return err
    }

    // try to unmarshal the data with a struct
    err = json.Unmarshal(b, &m.DataStruct)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    log.Println("got struct")

    r.Data = append(r.Data, m.DataStruct.Data)
    return nil
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/YIPeYv4AfT

Comment: Thanks jimb, I like this and will give it a go. 
qq - Do you think there will be an efficiency problem with this as you are trying to do something that will fail? While typing I now thinking I should't worry about such a small thing.