# JSON sometimes array sometimes object

Tags: json, go

I am consuming an API who's response for a particular field is sometimes and object and sometimes and array of object.

I created a struct to unmarshall the json response and it works great. However, in the instances where the json response has an array of objects, obviously the unmarshalling fails. How can I deal with this situation in Go?

```
Single Response:
{
    "net": {
                "comment": {
                    "line": {
                        "$": "This space is statically assigned",
                        "@number": "0"
                    }
                }
            }
}


Array Response:
{
    "net": {
                "comment": {
                    "line": [
                        {
                            "$": "All abuse issues will only be responded to by the Abuse",
                            "@number": "0"
                        },
                        {
                            "$": "Team through the contact info found on handle ABUSE223-ARIN",
                            "@number": "1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
}
```

I thought about creating 2 versions of the struct and then somehow determining which instance I got back, but this feels quite wasteful. I have also tried unmarshalling into map[string]instance{} but I got a bit lost and wasn't sure if I was headed down the right path.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32346117/unmarshalling-a-json-that-may-or-may-not-return-an-array and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33569210/go-json-unmarshal-options

Comment: Thanks again @JimB  I used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32346117/unmarshalling-a-json-that-may-or-may-not-return-an-array to figure this out. Took me some time to get my head wrapped around it, but there you go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried unmarshall into map[string]interface{}?

```
    type Net struct{
        Comment map[string]interface{} `json:"comment"`
    }
```

Then Comment["line"] value is possible array or object.

Comment: Thanks all. Lê Ngọc Thạch this is the simplest and most elegant solution. Thanks much!

Comment: This does not seem to work for the array case.  Its only picking up single objects.  How do you iterate through an array of objects using this method?